# Imageview is not showing my image?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, drawable

My image shows on Android Studio itself, but when uploading to my phone the image is gone. Maybe it's a too big image?
It's `1900 x 1250` pixels.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong..

[image]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#fed136" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Portfolio"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:backgroundTint="#fed136"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#fed136" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />
```

Comment: post your layout as a code so that everyone can edit and help to solve your problem. Code in image is not readable enough.

Comment: And yes, the image may be too large. Keep the image in drawable-xxxhdpi folder and see if it appears in your phone.

Comment: But thats the problem, where is my drawable-xxxhdpi folder???

Comment: create a new folder inside your res folder named drawable-xxxhdpi and put the image there and check if it helps

Comment: Check the logs. If the image was too big then there should be a log telling you that.

Comment: "Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Luca\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\src\main\res\drawable\drawable-xxxhdpi'. File already exists."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the layout looks okay. Try to place the image in drawable-xxxhdpi folder. Create a folder inside your res folder and name it drawable-xxhdpi if its not there. Place the large image inside this folder and check if that helps.

If not, please resize your image as this is the only problem you've here I guess. Too large image causes out of memory error in low-end devices.

Answer (score 1):

I could not place a comment, but try to look for the image view in your activity. It could be because your code is overriding it from there.

also limit the size of your imageview from the layout xml to make sure its loaded correctly.

And from experience with large photos, they normally not loaded easily on an emulator. so try smaller image as a last step.